# Random numbers arraylist

Tags: networking, file-io, arraylist

I'm new to Java. I'm having a hard time finding the solution to my assignment and the following is what I've gotten so far. The issue at the moment is whenever the system prints out the arraylist, numList, it is displayed with brackets and commas, which I do not want.

Use an array or Array List and generate 20 random numbers (Integer values between 0 and 100. 100 not inclusive). The program should perform the following tasks.
 1. Write the numbers from the array or Array List to a file.

*I'm able to create 20 random numbers but I don't know how to get rid of the "[" and ",". Can anyone help? And also I apologize to whoever saw my post yesterday. I should have read the instruction carefully before giving out only questions. Thanks!

```
public class random write {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IO Exception{

        Random generator = new Random();

        ArrayList numList = new ArrayList();

        int i = 0;

        while( i < 20 ) {
            int numGen = generator.nextInt(100);
            numList.add(numGen);
            i++;
        }

        System.out.print(numList);
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you `System.out.print(numbGen)` in the while loop itself? Play around & you'll do it on your own.

Comment: What "[" and what "," are you trying to get rid of?

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println` uses an objects default `toString()` method. For what you want to do, it would be better to just loop through the elements in your ArrayList and print them individually.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `System.out.println(numList);`

try this:

```
String result = numList.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
result = result.replace(",", " ");
```

and then:

```
System.out.println(result)
```

or if you want it the tough way, you can actualy override the `toString()` method of the `ArrayList` and use it in your application. It is strongly discouraged, though.